# How does the connection of constant-phase surface in Schwarzschild spacetime work?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am stuck while following the calculation of constant-phase surface of Hawking radiation in Hawking's original paper (Particle Creation by Black Holes, S.W. Hawking, [*Commun. Math. Phys.* **43**, 199 (1975)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02345020)).

My problem is following while calculating $p_\omega ^{(2)}$ below figure 4. Hawking tells that if we parallely transport $n^a$ along the generator of the event horizon then $-\epsilon n^a$ will connect a surface of constant phase from the original point x on the event horizon. I cannot get around this idea using any equation ─ so, how should I proceed?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks for the edit. It was my first time citing a problem from a paper so I will take note of this format while citing a paper.

Comment: which part exactly are you struggling with? The concept of parallel transport or the notion of constant phase? Please elaborate a bit.